# Password field show my password out

Tags: asp.net, model

I have 2 password models like this (in Accountmodel):

in class RegisterModel

```
[Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

But when I run my code, it still show my password out

[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'But when I run my code, it still show my password out'?  You can register with different passwords?  It lets you submit the model?

Comment: @BrianMains I want when I type my password it shows ******* instead of my text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatypes don't change the UI for these controls, unless you set it up to work that way (see the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information).  You can also change Html.TextBoxFor to Html.PasswordFor in the UI.